# Oracle PL/SQL developer data generator

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer version 21.4.2.018.1706-x64 and I can't find the tool Data Generator.

I know that in older versions of SQL Developer it was in the Tools tab but in my version it's not... (like you can see on the picture)

[image]

In older versions the tools tab is like this:
[image]

If you know where it is, I will be very grateful.

Thank you for your time

Comment: These are two different tools. Oracle SQL Developer <> Allround Automations' PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: Ok.. so in my version I can't use DataGenerator? @ThorstenKettner

Comment: What was being said was that previously you had installed the "PL/SQL Developer" application developed by the Allround Automation company and now you have installed the "SQL Developer" application developed by "Oracle Corporation" and they are two different products made by different companies with different feature sets. It is like asking why can I not find a feature of Microsoft Office 365 when I am using LibreOffice and not Microsoft Office. If you install the same software that you had before rather than different sfotware then you may find it has the features you remember.

Answer (score 2):

Those are two different tools, PL/SQL Developer from Allround Automations is NOT Oracle SQL Developer.

Different products, different companies, even different user audiences. One's free, one's not. So they're similar in many ways, but not in many more.

*Disclaimer: I'm the product manager for SQL Developer at Oracle.*

Comment: Thank you very much, there is a way to fill a lot of data in a random or automatic way in Oracle SQL Developer (like Data Generetor does) ?

Comment: No we don't have that feature, but APEX does with it's QuickSQL tech.